# Swap elements of 3 lists and make 4 lists

Tags: python

I want to make 4 lists from 3 given lists by swap last three elements.e.g

[image]
[image]

e.g my list is

```
a=[[1,0,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,0,0]]
```

and i want

```
b=[[1,0,0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0,1]]
```

And i also want to do this on any even number list e.g lists of 8 elements then last four element will swap.

My code seems something like this

```
n=8
chromosome=[[6, 4, 3, 5, 0, 3, 1, 0], [6, 2, 7, 6, 0, 4, 7, 5], [0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 6]]
        for i in range(0,int(n/2)):
            flag1 = False
            flag = False
            for j in range(0,n):
                if (i)!=n/(n/2):
                    if flag1==False:
                        chromosome2[i].append(chromosome[i][j])
                        if int((n-1)/2)==j:
                            flag1 = True
                    else:
                        chromosome2[i].append(chromosome[i+1][j])
                else:
                    if flag==False:
                        chromosome2[i].append(chromosome[i+1][j])
                        if int((n - 1) / 2) == j:
                            flag = True
                    else:
                        chromosome2[i].append(chromosome[i - 1][j])
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Is it generating an error? If so, please include the full traceback in the body of the question. Is it providing incorrect results? If so, describe the output for a given input. Also, please make sure your code is formatted correctly. As is, it has at least one indentation error.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask the question? Also, your illustration of the problem still isn't very clear on *what* you want to do. If there is something wrong, we need a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join the first half of one list with the second half of a different list, not the last three elements

```
first, middle, last = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]

split_point = len(first) // 2

b = [
    first[:split_point] + middle[split_point:],
    middle[:split_point] + first[split_point:],

    middle[:split_point] + last[split_point:],
    last[:split_point] + middle[split_point:],
]
```